# How many possible DAGs are there with $n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

I am have $n$ vertices and trying to enumerate all possible DAGs $\theta$ over $n$. How many DAGs are there? For example when $n=2$, there are 3 possible DAGs and when $n=3$ I tried the following:

$|E|=0$,  $|\theta|=1$

$|E|=1$, $|\theta|=6$

$|E|=2, |\theta|=8$

$|E|=3,|\theta|=3$

what is the general formula for counting the number of DAGs with $n$ vertices?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This may be too late to be of much help, but I found the following in the documentation for Kevin Murphy's Bayesian Network Toolbox, which can be found  [here](http://bnt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/usage.html#structure_learning) ([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140626142205/http://bnt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/usage.html)).

The number of DAGs as a function of the number of nodes, $G(n)$, is super-exponential in n, and is given by the following recurrence:

$$G(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}{n \choose k}2^{k(n-k)}G(n-k)$$

---

The page also lists the number of DAGs for up to 10 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find answer to these and similar questions also on the Online Encyclopedia for Intersequences, for example entry [A003024](https://oeis.org/A003024) gives the number of acyclic digraphs (or DAGs) with $n$ labeled nodes (starting at 0):

```
1, 1, 3, 25, 543, 29281, 3781503, 1138779265, 783702329343, 1213442454842881, 4175098976430598143, 31603459396418917607425, 521939651343829405020504063, 18676600744432035186664816926721, 1439428141044398334941790719839535103
```